# Extracting data from input file?

Tags: c

I've been stuck on this problem for a while.

I'm creating a program that that reads in an input file (just a plain .Txt) This input file stores variables in the following format:

```
x
21
% This is a comment
y 
3
```

And so on. My goal is to read this input file (done), and then store every variable in the file into a global variable in my c program. I.e. Global variable x will have the value 21 and y will have the value 3 in my c file, whilst comments are ignored.

I've thought about this for a while and can't figure out what functions to use. Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks.

(note that these variables will always have the same names, but the order in which they are presented will differ from input file to input file).

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You cannot make a new variable with a specific name determined at run-time.

Comment: Python does this by keeping all variables in a dictionary.

Comment: Variable *names* only exist inside your C source, not in the compiled executable. In some cases, even the variable *values* may get optimized out altogether.

Comment: @cool Guy I can't tag you. I'm not creating any new variables, these variables are already created and will have the same name in eveey input file, sorry.

Comment: F.Tahir If so, you should edit your question to clarify that. @Jongware also thought the same thing I did.

Comment: @F.Tahir, please show us what have you tried.

Comment: I have edited it. Basilevs I have tried using fscanf but right now am not at my pc so cannot post my code.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to have a struct with two fields.

```
struct Foo
{
  char var_name;
  int var_value;
};
```

Then you create an array of these structs, with the size of the expected variables in your input file.

```
struct Foo input_array[n];
```

Then, as you read your file, you set the struct fields...

```
for(int i = 0; i < n ; i++){
   input_array[i].var_name = input_var_name;
   input_array[i].var_value = input_var_value;
}
```

Afterwards you print the values, and they will already be in order.

Comment: Thanks.  Reading the file is the problem though

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we need the variables to read the values into:

```
int x, y, z /* etc */;
```

Now, lets make an array of pointers so that we can easily access the variables:

```
int *array[] = { &x, &y, &z /* etc */ };
```

Now, we need a `FILE*` to access the file:

```
FILE* fp;
```

Opening the file:

```
fp = fopen("filename.txt", "r"); /* 'r' for reading */
```

Checking if the file opened successfully:

```
if(fp == NULL)
{
    printf("Error opening file");
    exit(-1); /* Exit the program */
}
```

Now, reading the file using `fscanf`:

```
int counter = 0; /* For keeping track of the array index */
for(;;) { /* Infinite loop */
    int retVal = fscanf(fp, "%d", array[counter]); /* Capture return value of fscanf */

    if(retVal == 1) /* Successfully scanned a number */
    {
        counter++;
    }
    else if(retVal == 0) /* Failed to scan a number */
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%*s"); /* Discard a word from the file */
    }
    else /* EOF */
    {
        break; /* Get out of the loop */
    }
}
```

Now, printing the scanned data:

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    printf("%d", *array[i]);
```

and finally, closing the file:

```
fclose(fp);
```

---

Full code, added with @Jongware's suggestions:

```
int x, y, z /* etc */;
int *array[] = { &x, &y, &z /* etc */ };

char line[1024];
const char *varNames[] = { "x", "y", "z" };

int tmp = -1;

FILE* fp;
fp = fopen("filename.txt", "r"); /* 'r' for reading */

if(fp == NULL)
{
    printf("Error opening file");
    exit(-1); /* Exit the program */
}


int counter = 0; 
for(fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin)) { 
    if(line[0] == '%')
        continue;
    else
    {
          tmp = -1;

          for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(varNames) / sizeof(*varNames); i++)
          {
              if(strcmp(line, varNames[i]) == 0)
              {
                  tmp = i;
                  break;
              }
          }

          fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
          sscanf(line, "%d", array[tmp]);
    }
}

int i;
for(i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    printf("%d", *array[i]);

fclose(fp);
```

---

<sup><sub>All the above code is untested</sub></sup>

Comment: Thanks for this. Does this save it into the declared variables x, y? What if the order is swapped in the input file?

Comment: "_Does this save it into the declared variables x, y?_" Yes. "_What if the order is swapped in the input file?_" -- You don't seem to understand what the program does. It scans *values* from the file and stores each of them in the order given in `int *array[] = { &x, &y, &z /* etc */ };`. Try the program. You'll understand more when you try it.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll check it out when I'm home - appreciate the help. Thanks

Comment: Ah I see what's going on. The problem with this is that there's a chance that if a variable is stored as x in the input file, if it's the 3rd variable in the input File, it will be stored as z in the program.  Currently trying to think of ways to refine this behavior.

Comment: You need to add another few lines to (1) read the variable name as well, and (2) create a parallel array containing only the variable names to compare against.

Comment: @Jongware I'm getting really confused. How do I create a parallel array? Is it like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32934130/edit/)(The code is in a comment at the end of the answer)?

Comment: Yes, you got it (I didn't run, but it looks good). Instead of `char varNames[] = "xyz";`, use `char *varNames[] = { "x", "y", "z" };` so you can use `strcmp` (and longer variable names). With that, the `varNames` array is entirely parallel to the array of *addresses*, so you can use the index you get from comparing to write the value in. (Using a `struct` as CiceroDev suggests is pretty much the same; but apparently "reading the file is the problem".)

Comment: @Jongware Looks ok now?